# JavaScript replace regex by regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some text, which contains a markdown link:

```
var text = 'some text some text [some text](link.md) some text some text';
```

I want to change that to

```
var newText = 'some text some text [some text](link.html) some text some text';
```

basically, changing the .md to .html, but only if it's a valid markdown link. A valid markdown link is `[]()` with text between it.

Currently I have to following regex: `/\[.*\]\(.*.md\)/g`.

However, how will I perform a regex replace in Javascript (if the regex above matches, replace .md with .html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this replacement:

```js
var text = '[some text](link.md)';
console.log("Before:\n" + text);
text = text.replace(/(\[[^\]]+\])\(([^\)]+).md\).*/, "$1($2.html)");
console.log("After:\n" + text);
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you should use non-greedy mode `*?` instead of the gready one `*`. Then you should group the texts and use those groups to generate a new url:

```
str = str.replace(/\[(.*?)\]\((.*?).md\)/g, function(match, text, href) {
    return "[" + text + "](" + href + ".html)";
});
```

Shorter using an arrow function:

```
str = str.replace(/\[(.*?)\]\((.*?).md\)/g, (match, text, href) => 
    "[" + text + "](" + href + ".html)"
);
```

**Example:**

```js
var text = '[some text](link.md)';


text = text.replace(/\[(.*?)\]\((.*?).md\)/g, (m, text, href) => "[" + text + "](" + href + ".html)");

console.log(text);
```

Comment: I was writing and answer using `$1` and `$3` but I quit in shame after seeing this lovely example clarity.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a lookbehind:

```
text.replace(/(?<=\[.*?\])\((.*)\.md\)/, "($1.html)")
```

It's possible to do it without one by capturing the first part.

Edit:

There are two minor changes to make this work with multiple items in a string.  First, add the obvious "g" flag to the regex.  But, secondly, make the captured match non-greedy:

```
text.replace(/(?<=\[.*?\])\((.*?)\.md\)/g, "($1.html)")
```

As others have pointed out, you can capture the text in the square brackets and also substitute it, but this is a perfect example of using lookbehinds.

Comment: This seems to only work on the last instance in a string like '[some text](link.md) [some other text](anotherlink.md) '

Comment: This code [doesn't appear to be working](http://rextester.com/ZGII88483).  I seem to recall that you can't use a loosbehind for a replacement (I also thought of doing this here).

Comment: It works in the latest version of Chrome.  They added lookbehind support recently to Javascript.